# Confusing C++ compiler error, "cannot convert 'X' to 'double' in return

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, compiler-errors

I am relatively new to C++ programming and building a small program in Dev C++ which is producing the following compiler output:

```
Compiler: Default compiler
Building Makefile: "C:\Documents and Settings\s0237326\My Documents\Postgrad_Research_Sync_Folder\C_Projects\mfemm2\Makefile.win"
Executing  make...
make.exe -f "C:\Documents and Settings\s0237326\My Documents\Postgrad_Research_Sync_Folder\C_Projects\mfemm2\Makefile.win" all
g++.exe -c NOSEBL.CPP -o NOSEBL.o -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/include"  -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/backward"  -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/mingw32"  -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2"  -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include"   

NOSEBL.CPP: In member function `double femmedata::CNode::GetDistance(double, double)':
NOSEBL.CPP:24: error: cannot convert `CComplex' to `double' in return

NOSEBL.CPP: In member function `double femmedata::CBlockLabel::GetDistance(double, double)':
NOSEBL.CPP:108: error: cannot convert `CComplex' to `double' in return

make.exe: *** [NOSEBL.o] Error 1

Execution terminated
```

The problem is with the implementation of my CNode class, with the 'femmedata::CNode::GetDistance(double, double)' function shown below, with line number to show the error location.

```
22 double CNode::GetDistance(double xo, double yo)
23  {
24      return sqrt((x-xo)*(x-xo) + (y-yo)*(y-yo));
25  }
```

The definition of the CNode class is shown below:

```
class CNode
{
    public:
        CNode();

        double x,y;
        int xs,ys;
        bool IsSelected;
        CStdString BoundaryMarker;
        int InGroup;

        double GetDistance(double xo, double yo);
        CComplex CC();
        void ToggleSelect();

    private:

};
```

The CNode class is declared in NOSEBL.h, and the implementation contained in NOSEBL.cpp. These files also contain other class definitions and implementations. However, the CComplex type is defined elsewhere in complex.h and complex.cpp, and introduced here through including the header file.

I built the program previously in VC++ 2010 Express Edition with no problems, so I don't know what the problem is here. In case it is relevant, the next few lines of text after the GetDistance function are shown below, which do reference the CComplex type.

```
CComplex CNode::CC()
{
    return CComplex(x,y);
}
```

Thanks

## EDIT 1

```
NOSEBL.CPP: In member function `double femmedata::CNode::GetDistance(double, double)':
NOSEBL.CPP:24: error: `class CComplex' used where a floating point value was expected
NOSEBL.CPP:24: error: aggregate value used where a float was expected

NOSEBL.CPP: In member function `double femmedata::CBlockLabel::GetDistance(double, double)':
NOSEBL.CPP:108: error: cannot convert `CComplex' to `double' in return

make.exe: *** [NOSEBL.o] Error 1
```

Comment: If you do something "stupid" like "return (double)sqrt((x-xo)*(x-xo) + (y-yo)*(y-yo));" does that "resolve" your problem?

Comment: Not really related to question: don't use Dev-C++ or the ancient GCC that comes with it. Really. Just don't.

Comment: You might want to consider using a newer compiler. The version of GCC that is bundled with DevC++ is extremely old -- older even than the latest version of DevC++ is. MinGW has much more recent versions available. (You might also want to use an IDE that's actually supported like `Code::Blocks`) The fact that things built correctly with VC10 may indicate a compiler bug, because your code is just fine on it's face.

Comment: Did you create a method named sqrt() which returns a CComplex somewhere?

Comment: What is `sqrt`? `#include <cmath>` and use `std::sqrt`. Maybe it's overloaded for CComplex and there is some implicit conversion invoked.

Comment: I need more info, can you ppaste also the content of the file NOSEBL.CPP around lines 24 and 108?

Comment: Dev C++ is using an old version of GCC, you could try to replace it with a newer version: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MinGW/BaseSystem/GCC/Version4/

Comment: @Doc I get the result in Edit 1 with your suggestion. I'll also consider using code::blocks, this compiler just happens to be the one available at my workplace.

Comment: @pmr I think this might have solved it, I hadn't noticed I'd forgot to include math.h or cmath or anything in my headers. I'm still getting errors but unrelated to these files now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are getting the wrong `sqrt` function. You appear to have included the `<complex>` header but not the `<cmath>` header. The `double` parameter is being promoted to a `complex` parameter because the version of `sqrt` that takes a `double` is not known to the compiler at that point.

Comment: hmmm, now what is the ettiquette here, technically pmr answered this correctly in the comments to my question before your answer. If pmr doesn't supply a full answer in the next 5 mins or so I'll accept your answer. Thanks!

Comment: @crobar, I don't know why pmr chose to make that a comment rather than an answer. I can only say that I came to the same conclusion independently. The etiquette should be based on what is likely to be seen by future viewers of the question. If you want to give pmr an opportunity to convert the comment to an answer and accept it, that's perfectly fine.

Comment: I just took a stab in the dark. Anyway, your guess was much more specific. Didn't think someone would actually include `complex` when there is a home-brewn `CComplex` around.